# How to start keycloak with different java then is in the system

Tags: keycloak

I would like to start Keycloak with different java version that is currently installed on the system.

Is this possible and if yes how?

For different port I can use

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

Comment: You can set in standalone.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can use `export JAVA_HOME` before run `./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000`. For example,

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)

# Change from OpenJDK to Oracle Java and startup
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
$ ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```